# filter_fields with DjangoFilterBackend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I have a model called Product

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id
    name
    created_at
    updated_at
    price
    and so on....
```

i want to filter using all of the above attributes, which will be passed in query_params

at this moment i am using DjangoFilterBackends with filter_fields
but to support all attributes i have to mention all the attributes in filter_fields like below in views

```
filter_fields = ['id', 'name', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'price']
```

its working fine, but in actual model the fields are alot, which is causing code quality degradation.

is there any way to include all fields in filter_fields ??
i tried `filter_fiels = ['__all__']`, but its not working.

Comment: For clarification, please show the `REST_FRAMEWORK` dict from `settings.py`.

Comment: I would try `filter_fields = '__all__'`. In other context where this syntax is used, it is just a string, not a list.

Comment: IT WORKED !!! Thanks alot !! i am using filterbackends in the view itself filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend]